# getting error while grabing JSON in swift3

Tags: json, swift, swift3, swift2, getjson

```
class Get {

class func JSON(url:String,callback:@escaping (NSDictionary)->()) {
    requestJSON(url: url,callback: callback)
}

class func requestJSON(url:String,callback:@escaping (NSDictionary)->()) {
    var nsURL = NSURL(string: url)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: nsURL as! URL) {
        (data,response,error) in
        var error:NSError?

        var response = JSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary
        callback(response)
    }
    task.resume()
}
}
```

---

getting error in this line "var response = JSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary" as extra argument 'error' in call

[please help me in sorting this error or please suggest me link for grabing JSON library.thanks in advance.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkACX.jpg)

Comment: Try removing 'error: &error' from your response call.

Comment: @dylanthelion thanks for replying when i removed that i got this error         "call can throw but it is not marked with 'try' and error is not handled "

Comment: That means that JSONObjectWithData: throws, and needs to be put in a try block. I think you need to find a more recent example of the method you're using. JSON serialization was updated with Swift 3. You're using an implementation that worked a couple of years ago, but has essentially been deprecated,

Comment: @dylanthelion sir can u please help me in sorting  this problem i have to show the final output of our project by tomato.tanks in advance.

Comment: I am unfortunately too busy to give you a direct answer, but Googling 'swift jsonobjectwithdata' and filtering to the last month, gave me this: https://www.raywenderlich.com/150322/swift-json-tutorial-2 and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42242535/objective-c-to-swift-nsdata-with-nsjsonserialisation . Try these, and if they don't work, try filtering your searches for the past month. You're using an old method, and simply need an update.

Comment: @dylanthelion tank so much sir ill try this

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to enclose the method in a `try...catch` block.

Just replace these two lines

```
var response = JSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary
        callback(response)
```

with

```
do{
    let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)
    if let response = jsonObject as? NSDictionary{
        callback(response)
    }
}
catch{
    print(error)
}
```

You can also do this instead

```
if let response = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)) as? NSDictionary{
    callback(response)
}
```

Comment: bro tanq so much ..... the problem is solved love u soo much.....